# How did we figure out the charge and spin of the quarks that make up protons, electrons, and neutrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin

Wouldn’t the act of measuring the spin of these quarks effectively change their spin and then change the subatomic particle? Would this go against the law of conservation of charge?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(cross_section_ratio)

Comment: maybe reading the history of how quarks were deemed necessary to model the protons , even though they could not be seen independently, will help,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#History

Answer (score 2):

They were *inferred* by your proverbial "we". You are using spin   in two senses:

1. Spin multiplet representation index, i.e. the dimensionality of the spin multiplet reduced by one, and divided by two, $(d-1)/2=s$, so the labelling Casimir of the multiplet *s(s+1)* is 3/4. This is necessary for working out consistent wave functions of hadrons in accord with the symmetries dictated by the Pauli principle. It took a while, and the introduction of "color" for the quark model to completely gell.
2. Eigenvalue of $S_z$; for example, the $S_z$ of each of the three quarks of a $\Delta^{+}$ of *s=3/2* whose $S_z=3/2$ is measured (notionally) ***must*** be 1/2, by the rules of spin addition.

Like most properties of quarks, this is inferred indirectly consistently with basic principles.

I have no clue what the conservation of charge has to do with anything here. Hot tip: quarks do not make up electrons.